# Limit of a function approaches L then limit of sequence approaches L

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Im doing calculus 2. I have no knowledge of real analysis or something at the same difficulty level. Im confused about the following rule.

If f(x) $\to$ L as x $\to +\infty$, then f(n) $\to$ L as n $\to +\infty$. However if f(n) $\to$ L as n $\to +\infty$ then it is not true that  f(x) $\to$ L as x $\to +\infty$.

1. The rule says that if f(x) approaches L then f(n) approaches L.
2. The rule also says that the converse is not true. The explanation to why the converse is not true was explained by someone as follows:
   R doesnt just contain the sequence n. f(x)=1 if x is a natural number and 0 if x is not a natural number

What I understood from that is that some functions act differently when x is a natural number and when x is a real number.

If some functions act differently according to what type of number x is, then what guarantee is there that if f(x) converges, f(n) will not diverge or converge to a different limit?

Comment: What is your definition of $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=L$?

Comment: Natural numbers are real numbers...

Comment: @JulioPuerta The definition of a limit of a function is as follows: A function f(x) defined on some open interval that contains the number 'a', except possibly at 'a' itself. If for every number e>0 there is a number delta >0 such that if 0<|x-a|<delta then |f(x) - L| < e .

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla I know that natural numbers are included in real numbers so whats your point?

Comment: That "... some functions act differently when x is a natural number and when x is a real number" doesn't make sense. In any case, the idea of function implies that $f(x)$ **depends** of $x$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla What I meant was that taking the limit of f(x) as x goes to infinity but 'x' is a natural number. The limit of that would be different if 'x' was a real number

Comment: $f(x)\to L$ as $x\to+\infty$ ($x$ real) implies **trivially** $f(n)\to L$ as $n\to+\infty$ ($n$ integer) because all the natural numbers are real numbers.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla It is true that all natural numbers are included in real numbers but the fact is that not all real numbers are natural numbers. So we dont know whether the number at infinity is natural or real. I know infinity isnt a number but think of it this way. If a function for all natural numbers reaches a limit L but for all real numbers it reaches a limit M, then how is the rule correct? f(x) $\to$ M as x$\to +\infty$ then saying f(n)$\to$ M as x$\to +\infty$ is wrong.

Comment: The **opposite** implication is wrong. "For all naturals" is **less** than "for all reals".

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Thats what I said. "not all real numbers are natural numbers"